# Spritekit gestures are delayed

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, 2d

I have a spritekit project where I display a ball and I can swipe to move it left/right/top/down, the problem is that from the moment the scene is presented until the moment the actual swipe works takes around 2 seconds, after that initial hiccup it works flawlessly, but each time I start that scene it happens this

this is called on viewDidLayoutSubviews once:

```
-(void)addScene
{
//    viewGame.showsFPS = YES;
//    viewGame.showsNodeCount = YES;
//    viewGame.showsPhysics = YES;

    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    viewGame.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;
    viewGame.allowsTransparency=YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:viewGame.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    scene.delegateScene = self;

    // Present the scene.
    [viewGame presentScene:scene];

    [scene initialSetup];
}
```

and code for the scene did move to view:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    // Set scene to handle the swipe gesture for each direction

    NSLog(@"didMoveToView");

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
    swipeGestureUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureUp];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
    swipeGestureDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureDown];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
    swipeGestureLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
    swipeGestureRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRight];
}
```

and I have these times in the console:

```
2016-04-19 18:43:45.171 GAMEX[9699:3900188] didMoveToView
2016-04-19 18:43:45.171 GAMEX[9699:3900188] initial setup start
2016-04-19 18:43:45.239 GAMEX[9699:3900188] initial setup end
2016-04-19 18:43:45.243 GAMEX[9699:3900188] <SKMetalLayer: 0x156277360>: calling -display has no effect.
2016-04-19 18:43:47.432 GAMEX[9699:3900188] handleSwipeGesture
2016-04-19 18:43:47.437 GAMEX[9699:3900188] handleSwipeGesture
2016-04-19 18:43:47.439 GAMEX[9699:3900188] handleSwipeGesture
2016-04-19 18:43:47.444 GAMEX[9699:3900188] handleSwipeGesture
2016-04-19 18:43:47.583 GAMEX[9699:3900188] handleSwipeGesture
```

As you can see the initial setup takes very little and also the move to view and I begin to touch and swipe as soon as the app shows on the screen but the method is detected after 2 seconds, is like something is keeping the main thread from receiving events.

And also for these 2 seconds if I enable showFPS it shows 1 fps and then after 2 sec it shows 60 fps.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your `addScene` method in `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. I can't give a better answer until I'll see the whole code of your view controller and scene.